# Python/Kivy - Replace value of a label in another screen calling a function

Tags: python, function, label, kivy

I have an app with 2 screens (`ScreenManager`).
I wrote a function in the second screen (`SettingsScreen`) and I want this function to update a label in the first screen.

Below the two classes:

```
class MenuScreen(Screen):
    count = NumericProperty(30)

class SettingsScreen(Screen):
    def set_20(self):
        self.count = 20
```

The classes are linked to a button and a label in the Kivy stylesheet with two different screens

```
<MenuScreen>:
    FloatLayout:
                orientation: 'horizontal'
                Label:
                    id: l_label
                    text: str(root.count)

<SettingsScreen>:
    BoxLayout: 
        orientation: 'vertical'
        padding: 50
        FloatLayout:
            Button:
                text: "20"
                on_release: root.set_20()
```

To be clearer, the user has to click on the `Button` in the `SettingsScreen` to set the value of the `NumericProperty` in the first screen to 20.

At the moment, if I click on the button nothing happens.

What you see above is an extract - The full code of the app is stored below if you want to see more.

**https://github.com/marcogdepinto/LifeCounter**

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that when your button gets clicked and calls the `set_20` method, that method is trying to set the property `count` of the `SettingsScreen` to 20. 
 In other words

```
def set_20(self):
        self.count = 20
```

would try to set the the count property inside the `SettingsScreen` (hence the word `self`) and it cannot find it. There is another `count` property inside `MenuScreen` which it knows nothing about.
 To fix this I think you should give an id to MenuScreen

```
<MenuScreen>:
   id: menu
```

and in the on_release method of the Button do

```
on_release: menu.count = 20
```

## EXAMPLE

**Python file**

```
 class MenuScreen(Screen):
        counter = NumericProperty(0)

 class SettingsScreen(Screen):
        pass

 class MyWidget(ScreenManager):
        pass


 class MyRandomApp(App):
        def build(self):
            return MyWidget()

 if __name__ == '__main__':                                                                      
        MyRandomApp().run()
```

## kv file

```
<MyWidget>:
    id:manager
    MenuScreen:
        id: menu
        name: 'menuscreen'
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            Label:
                text: str(menu.counter)

            Button:
                text: 'Go to S2'
                on_press: manager.current = 'settingsscreen'
    SettingsScreen:
        id: settings 
        name: 'settingsscreen'
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            Button:
                text: 'Click to edit label of Prev screen'
                on_press: menu.counter = 20
            Button:
                text: 'Go to S1'
                on_press: manager.current = 'menuscreen'
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I see. I just looked at the docs, I was a bit wrong to assume Kivy properties work like python class variables given they are declared at class levels. They work just like normal object properties which you declare with `self` keyword.

Comment: can you try to give MenuScreen an `id: menu` in kv file and in Button do `on_release: menu.count = 20`

Comment: After I give to MenuScreen the 'id: menu' in kv file and in Button the 'on_release: menu.count = 20' property, I am receiving the following error: 'NameError: name 'menu' is not defined.'

Comment: Can you take a look at the example I just added?

Comment: Ok, I have understood. Now I have to apply it to my app. Thank you!